# Does the Xbox One controller have pressure sensitive triggers?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

Really want to use this for driving games... *cough* Forza Horizon 2 *cough*

Answer (score 2):

Of course yes, it's their main purpose I think.

> A standard Xbox One controller features ten digital buttons, a syncing button, **two analog triggers**, two analog sticks and a digital D-pad.

Comment: I seem to recall talk of a 'Pro' version of the controller which allowed you to toggle the triggers from analog to digital modes (for twitch shooters). I'm not sure if it was an official Microsoft release or a third-party one, but I thought it worth mentioning.